# Regresión Lineal en Python

Tags: python, regresión-lineal

estoy intentando hacer una regresión en python con el siguiente código en Google Colab:

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=[0.024,0.048,0.06,0.072,0.12]
y=[3.20,6.51,7.22,9.42,14.05]
x=x.reshape(-1,1)
y=y.reshape(-1,1)
plt.scatter(x,y)
from sklearn import linear_model
regr=linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x,y)
# Veamos los coeficienetes obtenidos, En nuestro caso, serán la Tangente
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
# Este es el valor donde corta el eje Y (en X=0)
print('Independent term: \n', regr.intercept_)
```

me aparece el siguiente error y no sé cómo solucionarlo:                                             `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

Comment: Tienes que convertir x en un objeto de Numpy o en su defecto usar `x=np.reshape(x,-1,1)`. Dale un vistazo a la [documentación oficial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Answer (score 5):

Estás definiendo `x` como una lista de python, la cual no tiene un método `list.reshape()` definido. Tendrías que definir `x=np.array([...])` como un *array* de **numpy**.

```py
x=np.array([0.024,0.048,0.06,0.072,0.12])    # acá x se define como numpy array
x=x.reshape(-1,1)    # al ser un objeto que hereda de numpy puede llamar 'np.reshape' como 'x.reshape'
```

O como te recomienda @Isanchezo en el comentario, usar el método directamente del modulo numpy (np):

```py
x=[0.024,0.048,0.06,0.072,0.12]    # acá se define como lista python
x=np.reshape(x,(-1,1))    # utilizas la lista como argumento, no como objeto y 'punto-método'
```

Salida:

```
array([[0.024],
       [0.048],
       [0.06 ],
       [0.072],
       [0.12 ]])
```